# Spring AOP, log the execution of a method

Tags: logging, spring-aop

Is there a way to log the execution of a method, at a trace level (not just the return values/parameters, but the entire method, line by line) using spring AOP with aspectJ? If it's not possible using AOP, what would you suggest?

Comment: Suppose a method consist of 5 LOC, you want when and what each LOC did, is that correct ?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: Using Spring AOP it is not possible to trace line by line execution.

Comment: Is there an alternative?

Comment: No alternative in Spring AOP, perhaps community would be able to guide for other options.